# Hive is giving me empty list upon listening to changes made to an open box

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I have a hive box opened in the *main.dart* and set it to a *global* variable so am able to access it from all other classes.

Now in one of my classes (*settingsView.dart*) which is a **StatefulWidget** I am able to put data in the *box* in the form `Map<String,Map<String,dynamic>>`. To be specific the `Map<String,dynamic>` can be a `Map<String,String>` or `Map<String,List<String>>`. e.g.

```
{"1A":{"num_on_roll": "34", "subjects": ["Mathematics","English","Science",...]}}
```

Now I am also retrieving or reading this data and to display it in the UI the `"num_on_roll"` value in a *Text* widget and `"subjects"` value in a *Wrap*.

NOW THE PROBLEM.

The first (`"num_on_roll"`) is always updated in the UI successfully but the `"subjects"` values in the *Wrap* are never updated unless I do hot restart or quit application and start it afresh, by so doing all data will be displayed successfully.

I have tried using `ValueListenableBuilder` to listen for changes in the box.

> "class_constants" is the specific for the stored data which is Map<String,`Map<String,dynamic>>`.

```
ValueListenableBuilder(
  valueListenable: Hive.box("mainDB").listenable(keys: ["class_constants"]),
  builder: (context,Box box,child) {
    var clsConst = box.get("class_constants", defaultValue: {});
    
    return Wrap(
      children: List.generate(
          isPresent
              ? clsConst[classes[tab]]["subjects"].length
              : selectedSubjects.length,
          (index) => Text(
                "${isPresent ? clsConst[classes[tab]]["subjects"][index] : selectedSubjects[index]}, ",
                style: const TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
              )),
    );
  }
),
```

**Why is it that the data is store successfully but not displaying some part?**

Comment: is the same behavior happens when using Hive.box("mainDB").listenable();

Comment: Yes please. Initially it was Hive.box("mainDB").listenable() before I changed it to Hive.box("mainDB").listenable(keys: ["class_constants"]); and both gives same results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the proper solution myself.

Hive has problem retrieving growable list immediately it has been put in the box. Even you must await it else it can't store!

So trick is to change growable list to non-growable list.

```
List list = [];
 list.add(1);
 list.add(2);
 list.add(3);

// non-growable
List tempList = List.generate( list.length, (_)=> list[_], growable: false);

mainDB!.put('key',tempList)
```

;